# DB2, passing between odbc and mysql

Tags: php, mysql, db2, odbc

I'm trying to execute this following program  but I'm getting some errors (I've commented the lines that have errors with /**/, while normal comments have //)

Essentially I'm:

1. Selecting records from a mysql table where status is not 'S'
2. Holding the ID and status code for those records in an array
3. Pulling records from a table on an odbc connection that have the same order number (Mysql is order_id, odbc/db2 is INVNOZ as ORDERNUM)
4. Comparing the status between the two tables for each record
5. Looping to see if the status is still the same on the db2 connection, or if it has changed to 'S'
6. For orders where it has changed to 'S', store those order numbers in another array

So it's working up to the point where I start dealing with DB2 and I think a lot of it just has to do with how I'm using the variables between databases.

Maybe it's a mix between syntax and improper variable use, but I'm not sure exactly where to go from here. I've cleared some other errors but I'm still stuck on these.  I can answer any questions to clarify

```
    //Selecting Records with status other than 'S'
    $preShipmentOrders = "
            SELECT 
                order_id,
                order_status
            FROM order_status
            WHERE order_status <> 'S'
    ";

    $preShipResult = mysqli_query($mysqlConn, $preShipmentOrders);

    //Store all Order_id and order_status for records with status other than 'S'
    $PSOrderIds = array();

    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($preShipResult))
    {
    $PSOrderIds[] = $row['order_id'];
    $PSOrderIds[] = $row['order_status'];
    }

    print_r($PSOrderIds); //Up to this line works fine, prints correct Ids/Statuses 

    foreach($PSOrderIds as $PSOrderId){

    //Pull records from DB2 where INVNOZ = previous order_id and check to see if FSTATZ in DB2 is same status as previous query, or if it's now 'S' in DB2
    $orderCompareDB2 = " 

        SELECT 
            INVNOZ AS ORDERNUM,
            FSTATZ AS STATUS 
          FROM GPORTAFL
        WHERE  ORDERNUM = $PSOrderIds[order_id]    /*This gives - Notice: Undefined index: order_id in C:\check.php on line*/
    ";

    $compareResult = odbc_exec($DB2Conn,$orderCompareDB2); /*Error -  odbc_exec(): SQL error: [IBM][System i Access ODBC Driver][DB2 for i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN NOT RID ROW., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\check.php on line*/

    //If any of those db2 records now have 'S' in fstatz, store those order IDs/INVNOZ
    $matchedOrderIds = array();

    while($compareRow = odbc_fetch_array($compareResult)){      /*Error - odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\check.php on line*/

        if($compareRow[STATUS] == 'S'){

            $updatePlacement = "UPDATE jfi_sales.order_status SET is_placement = 1, date_updated = DATE(NOW()) WHERE order_id IN (" . implode(',',$matchedOrderIds) .") ";

            if(mysqli_query($mysqlConn, $updatePlacement)){
                echo "Update Successful";
            }else{
                echo "ERROR: Couldn't update. " . mysqli_error($mysqlConn);
            }
        }else{
            echo "FAILED";
        }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your loop needs to store the current data and then each iteration of the foreach loop will point to that element, you can then pick out the orderID from the data there...

```
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($preShipResult))
        {
        $PSOrderIds[] = $row;
    }
    foreach($PSOrderIds as $PSOrderId){
      $orderCompareDB2 = " SELECT 
            INVNOZ AS ORDERNUM,
            FSTATZ AS STATUS 
          FROM GPORTAFL
        WHERE  INVNOZ = '{$PSOrderId['order_id']}'
    ";

    $compareResult = odbc_exec($DB2Conn,$orderCompareDB2);
    if ( $compareResult === false ) {
         exit (odbc_errormsg($DB2Conn));
    }

    ...
```

The second error is due to the statement ending in `ORDERNUM =` as the substitution failed and the third error is due to the statement not compiling correctly.

Also added some error reporting in case the SQL fails to compile (although I hate using `exit()` this shouldn't normally get triggered.

Or to a shortcut for loading is

```
$PSOrderIds= mysqli_fetch_all($preShipResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

Comment: I was trying to correct it, but trying to do tooo many things at the same time ATM

Comment: I tried this latest revision and it does in fact fix the undefined_index, but I still get the odbc_fetch error

Comment: Is your order id numeric?  If it isn't - you need to add quotes round it in the SQL- `INVNOZ = '{$PSOrderId['order_id']}'`

Comment: I've also changed the column it uses for the search to `INVNOZ` as this matches the underlying table structure.

Comment: This is how the array looks now: 
  [119] => Array
      (
          [0] => 99742427
          [order_id] => 99742427
          [1] => I
          [order_status] => I
      )
Is that correct? The only error now is the use of undefined constant db2conn

Comment: D'oh!, this is me cutting and pasting in a browser, should be $DB2Conn.

Comment: You can change the fetch to something like `mysqli_fetch_array($preShipResult,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` as it's currently fetching the results as in both associative and numeric indexes.

Comment: Ah sorry, I should have seen that too!

Comment: Thank you I think that got it! One quick question and then I'll leave you alone forever: If I have an undefined index on :STATUS here ```if($compareRow[':STATUS'] == 'S'){``` Am I calling that wrong from DB2?

Comment: Try just `$compareRow['STATUS']` - also if in doubt - try `print_r()` the check the result contents.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you never actually construct a key within `$PSOrderIds` called `order_id`. you can confirm this by just running a `var_dump($PSOrderIds)` The solution is to adapt your `while()` loop with `$PSOrderIds[] = array('order_id'=>$row['order_id'], 'order_status'=>$row['order_status']);`

Your second error; `/*Error - odbc_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in C:\check.php on line*/` is because your first query failed. And the first query failed because it was never getting a correct value for `ORDERNUM`

Comment: Ok that definitely fixed the undefined index issue but I do still get the other two errors. The current array prints like so:
```  [220] => Array
     (
         [order_id] => 95462013
     )

 [221] => Array
     (
         [order_status] => I
     ) ```

Comment: @TomN. Please see my edit to what you should set `$PSOrderIds` too

Comment: Ok so now the array looks like: ``` [83] => Array
     (
         [0] => 91531067
         [order_id] => 91531067
         [1] => I
         [order_status] => I
     )```
But I'm getting all 3 errors again. Your first solution did get rid of the undefined_index error but I'm wondering if the array structure is still off

Comment: @TomN. I've updated once more but theoretically the first edit I made should have thrown errors because every 2nd element in your array is throwing `order_status` in your `ORDERNUM` query. However my second and third edit implicated a merge so every element of your array should give you an order_id

Comment: Ok I see what you mean. The array is straightened out now 

[109] => Array
    (
        [order_id] => 95185029
        [order_status] => I
    )
So I think I can work from that to resolve the errors now

Comment: Ok, now that I have the array structure correct, I think maybe the issue is just how it's being called in the db2 select statement

Comment: I'm not sure of how a `odbc` query is constructed but the error `Token <END-OF-STATEMENT> was not valid. Valid tokens: ( + - ? : DAY INF NAN NOT RID ROW., SQL state 37000 in SQLExecDirect in C:\check.php on line` says End of statment error?

Comment: @TomN. I finish work now so I hope Nigel can help you further with this issue. You may want to remove the "Answered" flag from my post until you can actually get your code fully working